# Setting up WiFi in Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: linux

I have Netgear WNA1100 (Athreos 9271) based USB WiFi DOngle. I cannot start wlan0.I have installed the required firmware in /lib/firmware. OS is Ubuntu Server 12.04

Following are my configurations:

root@ubuntu:~# lsmod | grep ath9k
ath9k_htc              90811  0
mac80211              436455  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_common           13781  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              391554  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common
ath                    19387  3 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
cfg80211              178679  3 ath9k_htc,mac80211,ath

/network/interfaces

auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

root@ubuntu:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0846:9030 NetGear, Inc. WNA1100 Wireless-N 150 [Atheros AR9271]

root@ubuntu:~# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

Answer (score 0):

`iwconfig` and the wireless extension (`WEXT`) interface is mostly obsolete and I believe that it is in the process of [being slowly removed](http://linuxwireless.org/en/developers/Documentation/Wireless-Extensions) from the kernel. Most modern wireless interface management tools on Linux use a more modern `netlink`-based interface, provided by the `cfg80211` subsystem.

I would suggest that you try the [`iw`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iw) instead of `iwconfig`.